# What is the best way to use absolute paths in PHP?

Tags: php, path

I have always used relative paths in PHP. Last time I have realized that there were something like absolute paths.

But what is the best way to use them?

```
getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT"); ?
dirname(__FILE__); ?
```

How do you deal with the implementation? Please give some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want to use files that are *"relative"* to the one in which I am writing some code, I'm always using :

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

This allows me to :

- have absolute paths that'll work everywhere, no matter to which server I deploy my application
- still use path that "look like" relative ones when I'm writting them.

For instance, to include a file that's in a "classes" sub-diretory, I would generally use :

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/MyClass.php';
```

Note that this will work even if you're executing your script from the command-line -- while a solution based on some kind of DocumentRoot will probably not work when not using a web-server.

And, with PHP >= 5.3, you can also use the `__DIR__` magic constant, which has exactly the same value as `dirname(__FILE__)`, but is evaluated at compile-time, and not execution-time -- which is a bit better for performances.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used `dirname(__FILE__)`, it works perfectly for what I need it to. I store it in a variable at the beginning of script execution which is carried along with any global data I use, then when I require or include new files I can easily include it into my paths without too much problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROT'] or $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

I donno, to everyone their own I suppose